# Ruby: create a double array from string based on a colon separator

Tags: ruby, string, multidimensional-array

I get a string with the following repeating pattern: label (one word), colon, some text (pretty much anything, even empty). For example:

```
"FileSize: 597262388 Duration_String: 1h 34mn Duration_string3: 01:34:12.564 Source_Duration:  Width: 712 Height: 360"
```

I am trying to create a 2D array based on the label and the following text:

```
[["FileSize", "597262388"], ["Duration_String", "1h 34mn"], ["Duration_string3", "01:34:12.564"], ["Source_Duration", ""],  ["Width", "712"], ["Height", "360"]]
```

I have tried this code:

```
medinfo = "FileSize: 597262388 Duration_String: 1h 34mn Duration_string3: 01:34:12.564 Source_Duration:  Width: 712 Height: 360"
mi = medinfo.split(':')
s = []
mi.each do |x|
    x2 = x.split(/\W+/).last
    x1 = x.gsub(x2, '')
    s << x1
    s << x2
end
mi_pairs = (s[1..-1].each_slice 2).to_a
```

But it doesn't work in all cases and I feel there must be a simpler ruby solution.

Comment: Is there any way you can change the input structure, or is it sourced outside your control? It's workable, but not a very parsing-friendly format. It would really help if there was some other separator between label/text pairs.

Comment: I agree it's not very parsing-friendly. And I wish I could change that structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script seems to work for me for the given cases:

```
medinfo = "FileSize: 597262388 Duration_String: 1h 34mn Duration_string3: 01:34:12.564 Source_Duration:  Width: 712 Height: 360"
arglist = medinfo.split /([\d\w_]+: )/
result = []
arglist.each_index {|i| result << [arglist[i].strip[0..-2], arglist[i+1].strip] if i.odd?}
```

You'll find your result in the `result` array.

Edit: You have a problem with my regex in case your values (not the keys) contain a word ending with a ": " (colon, space), as the regex scans for this pattern to separate the input.

Edit2: Found a minor flaw in the code. Every key ended with a ": ". The unnecessary substring is now stripped too.

Comment: This works beautifully.  I just put a minor modification as I found one of the keys (not in my example above) included a forward slash, so I wrote: arglist = medinfo.split /([\d\w_\/]+: )/  Many thanks.

Comment: Your welcome :)

By the way: If you find my answer acceptable. you are welcome to accept it ;)

Comment: In `[\d\w_]` `\d` and `_` are redundant. `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` already.

Answer (score 1):

Though you've got solution to your problem, this is just another solution to your problem:

```
medinfo = "FileSize: 597262388 Duration_String: 1h 34mn Duration_string3: 01:34:12.564 Source_Duration:  Width: 712 Height: 360"
str = medinfo.gsub(/([a-zA-Z_3]+)(:)/,'\1;')
mi = str.split(';')
s = []
mi.each do |x|
  x2 = x.split(/\W+/).last
  x1 = x.gsub(x2, '')
  s << x1.strip
  s << x2.strip
end
mi_pairs = (s[1..-1].each_slice 2).to_a
```